# how does this fix the state closure problem with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I am looking at the code in [formik](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16956) that apparently is a way around the stale closure problem with react hooks.

```
function useEventCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T): T {
  const ref: any = React.useRef();

  // we copy a ref to the callback scoped to the current state/props on each render
  useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  });

  return React.useCallback(
    (...args: any[]) => ref.current.apply(void 0, args),
    []
  ) as T;
}
```

I've seen this pattern a lot in other libs but I don't understand why this cures it.

I don't understand why creating a `ref` in a `useEffect()` cures anything.

Does it silence the linter?

Comment: You mean this would cure `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule? I think because [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) returns an `object that will persist for the full lifetime of the component.`. The linter knows this and won't complain about missing dependency that is a ref. But even if you add ref as a dependency it won't re create your return value for the component's life cycle since ref will never be re created.

Comment: Would it not be much easier to just do: `useCallback(
    () =>
      console.log('never changes during comp lifecycle'),
    []
  );` or are you passing a closure function to useEventCallback

Comment: I found this article helpful. If you have time, read all of it, otherwise, skip to Levels 9-12: https://medium.com/@sdolidze/the-iceberg-of-react-hooks-af0b588f43fb

Comment: @ArashMotamedi That's a nice article but does not explain the solution that this custom hook brings. Creating a function that has state in it's closure scope that will change that very state without creating a new function every time you change state.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback) actually states:

> > In either case, we don’t recommend this pattern and only show it here for completeness. Instead, it is preferable to [avoid passing callbacks deep down](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down).

Let's say we can't avoid passing callbacks then the simplest way would be to use a callback for the state setter: `setSomeState(currentState=>....return something based on current state)`

I'm not sure how this would behave when concurrent mode is released but here is an example of how you can use a callback to the state setter:

```js
const ParentContainer = () => {
  //list is created and maintained in parent
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, val: true },
    { id: 2, val: true },
  ]);
  //simplest way to get current list is to pass a callback
  //  to the state setter, now we can use useCallback without
  //  dependencies and never re create toggle during this life cycle
  const toggle = React.useCallback(
    id =>
      setList(list =>
        list.map(item =>
          item.id === id
            ? { ...item, val: !item.val }
            : item
        )
      ),
    []
  );
  return Parent({ list, toggle });
};
const Parent = ({ list, toggle }) => (
  <div>
    {list.map(item => (
      <ItemContainer
        key={item.id}
        item={item}
        //every item gets the same toggle function
        //  reference to toggle never changes during Parent life cycle
        toggle={toggle}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
//Added memo to make ItemContainer a pure component
//  as long as item or toggle never changes the (render) function
//  will not be executed
//  normally a pure component should not have side effects so don't
//  do side effects in pure compnents (like mutating rendered var)
//  it is only to visibly display how many times this function was
//  called
const ItemContainer = React.memo(function ItemContainer({
  item,
  toggle: parentToggle,
}) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  //toggling item with id 1 will not increase render for
  //  other items (in this case item with id 2)
  //  this is because this is a pure component and this code
  //  will not be executed due to the fact that toggle or item
  //  never changed for item 2 when item 1 changed
  rendered.current++;
  const toggle = React.useCallback(
    () => parentToggle(item.id),
    [item.id, parentToggle]
  );
  return Item({ toggle, item, rendered });
});
const Item = ({ toggle, item, rendered }) => (
  <div
    onClick={() => toggle(item.id)}
    style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
  >
    <div>{item.val ? '[X]' : '[-]'}</div>
    <div>times rendered:{rendered.current}</div>
  </div>
);

//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentContainer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```